# Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "myapp" target's entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, provisioning, ios-provisioning

I was working on an application and in middle of the application. My application is not working. I am working on free account that i created.
I did looked into similar questions none of them helped that's why i requestioned.

Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "myapp" target's entitlements.
Automatic signing can't add the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements to your provisioning profile. Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a matching provisioning profile from the developer website. Alternatively, to continue using automatic signing, remove these entitlements from your entitlements file and their associated functionality from your code.

Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.relationshipatpeace" doesn't include the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements.

Comment: I checked the dublicated answers they didnot solve my issue.

Comment: so as a last resort i had to repost this question.

Comment: Alot of people are having the same issue from yesterday. This seems to be an issue with apple servers. If u are testing try emulators

Comment: Apparantely the issue was from server side and have been resolved. I just needed to redownload the profiles.